# Android Studio layout design shows blank screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

When I try to to see the design of a layout, it shows a gray screen instead.This started happening in every project. Even the new projects that I didn't make any modifications on, so I'm sure this is not because of an error in the layout.
I'm using the lates Eel 2022.1.1 version.[image]

I expected to see the layout design as usual but I see a blank screen.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `File` -> `Invalidate Cache and Restart` or `Clean` and `Re-Build` Project again.

Comment: Does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Click on 'Split' button which is on right top corner, to toggle design and code or code with design.

If there any issue, will appear there.

[image]

Comment: There is no issue. This is a new project which I have made no modifications on.